# Post in MVC only returns editable fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post

I'm new to MVC.
I have a partial view with editable fields and not editable fields:

```
<li>
    <b>
        @Resource.Field1:
    </b>
    @model.Field1
</li>
<li>
    <b>
        @Resource.Field2:
    </b>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(sb => sb.Field2)
</li>
<input type="image" src="~/Resources/Images/DoSomething.png" border="0" alt="Submit" value="DoSomething" name="DoSomething"/>
```

The controller function:

```
[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton]
public ActionResult DoSomething(MyModel myModel)
{
    DoSomethingToManipulateTheModel(myModel);

    return PartialView("~/Views/MyPartialView.cshtml", myModel);
}
```

But I have a problem:
In the myModel object, that is passed the doSomething function, only the fields that are editable in the view are filled, all other fields are null. So I can't send the model back to the view because the view will only show the editable values.

Has anybody an idea how I can get all values back without making them all editable?

Answer (score 0):

Store your data in Session, or use HiddenField in Razor. 
Like this

@Html.HidddenBox(sb => sb.HiddenVariable)